# Ubuntu 19.04 on Thinkpad Yoga X390 Thunderbolt USB not working after sleep

Tags: usb, thinkpad, external-monitor, thunderbolt, external-soundcard

I'm trying to solve the not working (actually partially working) Thunderbolt dock once I connect it after Ubuntu is booted.

Partially, because on reconnecting Thunderbolt on the already booted system with Ubuntu 19.04 I cannot make USB devices working, while i.e. all monitors connected to the dock work well (not always, but usually).

This happens in the following scenario - boot my Yoga not connected to the Thunderbolt dock then connect to it;

If I face the situation above, rebooting help without the need to re-connect the dock.

If I connect the dock before starting Ubuntu, everything is fine and all devices connected to dock work.

I believe the problem is a "hot connect": USB somehow is not detected on hotplug when OS is run (or actually is partially connected, because displays connected to the dock wake up but none of the USB devices is visible.

The machine is Thinkpad Yoga X390 and the dock is HP Thunderbolt Dock G2 230W.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Got solution: as Thunderbolt happens to be controlled also by BIOS, disabling BIOS Assisted Thunderbolt in Thinkpad's BIOS helped, now all THunderbolt Devices work hot-plug.